# Load x-window from command line in Debian

Tags: linux, debian

I have Debian 8.5 Jessie installed. But I think I have a core version installed because when I log in I must do it from the command line.

What I want to do is to load the x-window system. I tried typing in the command line `apt-get install x-server-xorg-core` in order to know if x-window is installed and messages I read were:

`x-server-xorg-core` is already in your latest version 0 updated, 0 new files installed, 0 to remove and 0 not updated

So, I understand that x-window is installed. The problem is how can I load it.

How can I do it?

Here is the `source.list`:

```
 # deb cdrom: [Debian GNU/Linux 8.5.0 _Jessie_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 201606$

deb cdrom: [Debian GNU/Linux 8.5.0 _Jessie_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 201604$

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install. The following entries 
# for your mirror of choice.
```

Thanks.

Comment: The command is `startx` or as root : `service gdm start`

Comment: Have you installed a display manager? You must choose one when installing, e.g. Gnome and KDE both come with their own display manager, and there are generic display managers like `xdm` or `ligthdm`. The display manager should start X, and present you with a login screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bare `X`, yes, You do need `xserver-xorg-core` only. You can start it by typing `X` (You may have to set `DISPLAY` variable before that).

For minimalistic setup You should install `xinit` package plus any package providing `x-window-manager` and `x-session-manager` (e.g. `openbox`, `e17`, etc.). After this it should be possible to start `X` from the command line via `startx` command. This setup may be enhanced by e.g. `mingetty` and custom `.profile` for automatic login & automatic `X` startup on boot.

For a full-blown graphical environment You just install graphical display manager e.g. `gdm3` & the environment itself (e.g. `gnome`).

**Edit**:

I see that debian repositories are missing in Your `sources.list`. Since You are from Spain, You can add the following line to the sources list:

```
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

and update dpkg cache:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

You should be able to install the packages afterwords.

Comment: I don't have gnome nor kde in my repository. I must download it but I don't know how to do it, because I am using VirtualBox and I install debian using the first iso file.

Comment: @axmug: what do you mean by 'my repository'? Anyway, post your `sources.list`.

Comment: I posted the source.list file in the initial post

Comment: @axmug: see edit.

Comment: @axmug: De nada :) You can always get the list of debian mirrors [here](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) or use `apt-spy` to auto-select the fastest one for You.